# How to get the SELinux Type Enforcement (.te) file which contains all rules regarding certain type?

Tags: linux, selinux

I would like to change permissions of certain directories(with *user_home_t* type) to further disallow *guest_t* to perform some actions on them.
I thought to do so by creating new type (*protected_t*) and then not allowing *guest_t* the actions I don't want to be performed while leaving permissions regarding protected_t and other types the same as regarding *user_home_t* and other types.

The problem is that I don't know where to find policy that describes actions allowed between other types and *user_home_t* so that I can change it for *protected_t*. Generating the entirely new policy for *protected_t* and allowing what was denied in SELinux permissive mode didn't work well. MCS and MLS also can't be used.

Is there a way to get Type Enforcement file where all allow rules regarding *user_home_t* are written? I am using Linux Fedora 36.